# Java loses the last "/" character of the path

Tags: java, path, java.nio.file

I am developing a java application to perform operations with files.
In particular, I perform move and copy of files .. and I have programmed two functions.
Functions take strings such as `sourcePath` and `targetPath` as parameters.
I am developing on a mac, and I have given 777 permissions to the folders I need.
But I have the problem, that when I pass paths to the `copyFile` and `moveFile` functions I lose the last `"/"` of the path and consequently get a `java.nio.File: NoSuchFileException` exception.
I have read both the Java and online documentation but have not found any answers.

I accept any suggestion or advice ... I just add that by manually forcing the path inside the function, then not passing sourcePath and targetPath, the two functions behave as they should.

- copyFile:

```
public static boolean copyFile(String sourcePath, String targetPath) throws IOException {

        boolean fileCopied = true;
        // if i pass sourcePath i lost the last /
        File dirFiles = new File("/Users/myname/Documents/deleghe/remote/F24_CT/deleghe_da_inviare_a_icbpi/");
        File[] listOfFiles = dirFiles.listFiles();
        String dest = "/Users/myname/Documents/deleghe/local/F24_CT/deleghe_da_inviare_a_icbpi/";
        for (File file : listOfFiles) {
            Files.copy(file.toPath(),
                    (new File(dest + file.getName())).toPath(),
                    StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        }

        return fileCopied;
    }
```

- moveFile:

```
public static boolean moveFile(String sourcePath, String targetPath) throws IOException {

        boolean fileMoved = true;
        // if i pass sourcePath i lost the last /
        File dirFiles = new File("/Users/myname/Documents/deleghe/remote/F24_CT/deleghe_da_inviare_a_icbpi/");
        File[] listOfFiles = dirFiles.listFiles();
        String dest = "/Users/myname/Documents/deleghe/remote/F24_CT/deleghe_inviate/";
        for (File file : listOfFiles) {
            if (file.length() >= 968 && file.length() <= 2057) {
                Files.move(file.toPath(),
                        (new File(dest + file.getName())).toPath(),
                        StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                System.out.println("File spostato correttamente: " + file.getName() + "!! \n");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Non è stato possibile spostare il file: " + file.getName() + "!! \n");
            }
        }

        return fileMoved;
    }
```

Comment: Use `new File(dest, file.getName())` instead of `new File(dest + file.getName())`. The whole idea of having the class `File` is to *avoid* having to do string manipulation to get the name of some file (and to make it system agnostic). The name of a directory `foo` is just `foo`, it's not `foo/` (though that's a commonly used way to indicate a file name belongs to a directory).

Answer (score 1):

1. try to use `Paths.get(dest, file.getName()).toUri()` instead of `dest + file.getName()` (it is not best practice)
2. you are not losing anything, you just reading files from directory and your code is working without any exception. Check your directories and files inside them one more time

Comment: Avoid string concatenation - use `Paths.get(dest,file.getName())` and no `toUri()`